# using scipy.optimize curve_fit to find parameters of a curve and getting 'Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated'

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to use scipy.optimize to fit experimental data and got:

```
optimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',
```

Here is the data I am trying to fit **with exponential curve**:

[image]

here is the part of a code where I am trying to fit a data:

```
# using curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# defining a function

# exponential curve
def _1_func(x,  a0,b0,beta):
    """
    calculates the exponential curve shifted by bo and scaled by a0
    beta is exponential 
    """
    y = a0 * np.exp( beta * x ) + b0
    return y

# the code to fit
# initial guess for exp fitting params

numpoints = spectrum_one.shape[0]

x = F[1:numpoints] # zero element is not used
y = np.absolute(spectrum_one[1:numpoints])/signal_size

# making an initial guess
a0 = 1
b0 = y.mean()
beta = -100  

p0 = [a0, b0, beta]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(_1_func, x, y, p0=p0)
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)) # errors

print('Popt')
print(popt)
print('Pcov')
print(pcov)
```

**UPDATE1:**
The result is:

```
Popt
[ 1.00000000e+00  7.80761109e-04 -1.00000000e+02]
Pcov
[[inf inf inf]
 [inf inf inf]
 [inf inf inf]]
```

**UPDATE 2** - raw data for fitting is here in csv format: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wUoS3Dq_3XdZwo3OMth4_PT-1xVJXdfy/view?usp=share_link

As I understand ic pcov has inf - it shows that curve_fit can't calculate the covariance and the popt parameters can't be used they are not optimal for this data..

If I visualize the data I have next results:

[image]

Why am I getting this type of error?
(I thought it is an easy task for curve_fit)

Maybe I need to scale my data somehow?

Comment: You are getting a warning, not an error. So you should anyway get an output. What are you getting?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the results for the presented data - for better understanding.

Comment: You might want to try a different starting condition. Levenberg–Marquardt (LM) algorithm used in curve_fit() is sensitive to initial conditions, and I guess it may not converge from the initial condition you have entered (your starting a0 seems too large, shouldn't it be ~0.002 ? I am not sure why at zero frequency the fit did not jump to 1 as well).

Comment: Also, note that popt did not differ from your starting p0 (I am guessing maybe the gradient at the starting point is too small for the algorithm to have meaningful convergence). This answer might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371428/scipy-curve-fit-raises-optimizewarning-covariance-of-the-parameters-could-not?rq=1

Comment: I will try to use lmfit of course but I think the problem is with the data scaling. Maybe I should rescale the data before fitting? E.g. - y/y_max and x/x_max?

Comment: I have changed the initial guess several times and even used another solver for optimization, but still can't fit this data :) maybe I need to add some weights to the measurements so the data with greater magnitude will have bigger weights than data with lower magnitude (but it will shift the overall fit in this case)..

Comment: @twistfire If possible, please post your raw experimental data.

Comment: @adrianop01, I have updated initial question, link to the data in csv provided in UPDATE 2 section.

Comment: @adrianop01, can you share your code as an answer with some explanation so I can vote for your solution? another thing I want to see is how you rescale it back and how it fits actual data..

Comment: To be precise, it is not really a feature scaling problem but more of a zero gradient problem (Please refer to my answer for the detailed discussion), but x scaling does solve the zero gradient problem for your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Scaling up x before fitting the data to the exponential function solves this problem, or scaling down the starting beta value (refer to explanations for discussion).

```
# using curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

spectrum_one = np.genfromtxt('spectrum_one.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header = 1)

# defining a function
# you may also just change the starting beta value and get the same effects.
# x_scale = 1
x_scale = 10000000
y_scale = 1

# exponential curve
def _1_func(x,  a0,b0,beta):
    """
    calculates the exponential curve shifted by bo and scaled by a0
    beta is exponential 
    """
    y = (a0 * np.exp( beta * (x/x_scale) ) + b0)*y_scale
    return y

# the code to fit
# initial guess for exp fitting params

x = spectrum_one[:,0] # zero element is not used
y = np.absolute(spectrum_one[:,1])

# making an initial guess
a0 = 1
b0 = y.mean()
beta = -100 
# Scaling beta have same effect:
# beta = -100/10000000 

p0 = [a0, b0, beta]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(_1_func, x, y, p0=p0)
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)) # errors

print('Popt')
print(popt)
print('Pcov')
print(pcov)
```

Output of the covariance matrix and estimated coefficients are as follows:

```
Popt
[ 2.22681758e-03  6.16059861e-04 -2.69660695e+01]
Pcov
[[ 4.41126691e-09  1.26838432e-12 -5.34773724e-05]
 [ 1.26838432e-12  1.15025798e-10 -5.58666885e-06]
 [-5.34773724e-05 -5.58666885e-06  1.55785623e+00]]
```

Note that the above function can be directly used for curve fitting of original, unscaled data (x is unmodified frequencies):

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,_1_func(x,*popt))
```

[image]

### Explanation

The reason why the least square algorithm ([Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm)) fails to converge under the original starting condition is likely because of the **Jacobian** **J** at the starting point being **essentially a zero vector numerically**:

[image]
If we calculate the Jacobian with respect to coefficient vector **β**:

[image]

If x is in the original scale with your original `beta=-100`, the exponential components in the Jacobian will be very close to zero numerically. Thus, either the LM algorithm does not give a sensible value of coefficients increments **δ** = Δ**β** due to numerical stability issues (dividing by very small floating point values), or simply fails to converge because the Jacobian is essentially zero (refer to the above equation).

In fact, if you try a very small `beta = -100/10000000` at the beginning (such that the numerical value of exponential is not close to zero), without the data scaling **AT ALL** `x_scale = y_scale = 1`, the algorithm still converges:

```
Popt
[ 2.22681758e-03  6.16059861e-04 -2.69660695e-06]
Pcov
[[ 4.41126692e-09  1.26838469e-12 -5.34773723e-12]
 [ 1.26838469e-12  1.15025798e-10 -5.58666883e-13]
 [-5.34773723e-12 -5.58666883e-13  1.55785621e-14]]
```

[image]

You may want to refer to this answer for further discussions:
[scipy curve_fit raises "OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371428/scipy-curve-fit-raises-optimizewarning-covariance-of-the-parameters-could-not?rq=1)